# Tool to monitor bandwidth utilization per traffic (tc) class on linux

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, bandwidth, tc

Some time in the past, i came across a siple tool that showed live in a 1sec interval, in human readable format, the bandwidth utilization seperated per tc class on your linux server. Unfortunately, i don't remember the name of this tool, and i did not find anything similar. Maybe you know a command line tool that can produce this kind of output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the tool i was referring to in my initial post. I wanted to make a reference, if anyone else needs it in the future:

http://www.docum.org/docum.org/monitor/

it's the monitor_tc.pl script

Comment: Hi, do you possibly have a download link for this? It's broken on that site apparently..

Answer (score 3):

The simple way (with no overall bandwidth data) is to use 'tc -s -d qdisc show' which shows the packet and byte count per class.

There are several traffic graphing options that will turn that data into pretty graphs, but that's all I have for you.